# How to create a dependency property of type Type, and assign it in the XAML?

Tags: .net, silverlight

I'd like to know how I can assign in XAML a dependency property of type Type in Silverlight since the markup extension {x:Type} does not exist ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your requirement there may be a range of different approaches to take.  The following is very general solution.

Create a value converter which converts a string to a Type:-

```
public class StringToTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Type.GetType((string)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Place an instance of this converter in resource dictionary of which destination object has visibility, say the App.xaml:-

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:StringToTypeConverter x:Key="STT" />
    </Application.Resources>
```

Now in your Xaml you can assign a value to a property like this:-

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Source='System.Int32,mscorlib', Converter={StaticResource STT}}" />
```

Comment: I have an exception when I use it on custom type if I don't specify the version, but your solution seems to be the best we can do :(

Comment: @Nicolas Dorier:  For a custom type try just using the type name alone (that is instead of adding a version number, remove the assembly name).  If the custom type is in the same assembly as your Xaml/Usercontrol that is using this technique that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to decorate the property itself with a type converter.

Define a TypeConverter like this:

```
public class StringToTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
   public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
   {
     return sourceType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (string));
   }

   public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
   {
      var text = value as string;
      return text != null ? Type.GetType(text) : null;
   }
}
```

Decorate your property like this:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(StringToTypeConverter))]
public Type MessageType
{
    get { return (Type) GetValue(MessageTypeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MessageTypeProperty, value); }
}
```

And then in your XAML you can do this:

```
<MyObject MessageType="My.Fully.Qualified.Type"/>
```